# Authorize Users at Controller level from web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller the  `[Authorized]` annotation.

I'd like to go get a list of authorized users that are setup in my web.config file.

```
<add key="authorizedUsers" value="jeff,dan,mindy,claudia"/>
```

I know in the controller you can do something like:

```
[Authorize Users="jeff,dan,mindy,claudia"]
```

But I'd rather just update the web.config file without having to re-compile.  Is there anyway to do read the web.config file for my list and then add it to the `[Authorize]` attribute?  I'm also using Windows Authenticationfor this rather than Form Authentication.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement custom AuthorizeAttribute which inherits from AuthorizeAttribute.

*I assume you are using FormAuthentication. Otherwise, it won't work.*

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomUserAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string[] _usersSplit
    {
        get
        {
            var authorizedUsers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorizedUsers"];

            return authorizedUsers.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        return user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && (_usersSplit.Length <= 0 || Enumerable.Contains(_usersSplit, user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
[CustomUserAuthorize]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your page.";

    return View();
}
```

***FYI: Ideally, you want to use role based authentication, and store them in database. It is a little bit easy to maintain. However, it is up to your need.***

Comment: Can an array ever have a length less than zero?

Comment: @ErikPhilips It's the original source of AuthorizeAttribute; I just strip out other methods, and modify _usersSplit. ***Good catch!***

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it like that.  You need to setup these users into roles and then grant the roles access in the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="admin"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

You can do this;

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

but that opens the website to potential hacking IMO